# How to interpret the sentence--"A Mother beats up her Daughter as she was drunk"?

Tags: grammar, sentence

In the sentence above, who is drunk? I looked into the grammar book of my 7th grader (only grammar book I have access to at the moment) but could not find much. When searching on line, I found one page where the solution is essentially given from a cultural point of view which says the sentence could be interpreted as daughter being drunk because she is more likely to drink.

Is there any grammatical rule that would help disambiguate this sentence?

Comment: *"One morning I shot an elephant in my pajamas. How he got into my pajamas I'll never know."*

Comment: Closely related but posted on ELL: [How to interpret the sentence - “A Mother beats up her daughter because she was drunk”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/155336/how-to-interpret-the-sentence-a-mother-beats-up-her-daughter-because-she-was)

Comment: I would love to know who started this particular meme.